# Create WebApplication extension method in external library

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to create an extension method to register some routes in an external library using C# .NET 6.
I can'f find a way to do it because i cannot reference Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref where the WebApplication class is defined. 
Has anyone encountered this problem and found a solution?

Comment: What's preventing you from doing this?

Answer (score 6):

If I undertand your problem correctly:

1. You have a class library project (i.e. your `.csproj` file starts with

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
```

2. You want to create an extension method to `WebApplication` like

```cs
public static class SomeModule
{
  public static void DoSomething(this WebApplication webApplication)
  {
    // stuff
  }
}
```

As you can't reference `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref` you can try with adding a framework reference to your project as per [Use the ASP.NET Core shared framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/target-aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#use-the-aspnet-core-shared-framework) article.

```cs
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    
    <ItemGroup>
        <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <!--Rest of your project stuff-->
</Project>
```

and this way you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `IApplicationBuilder` from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions` to create external method for `WebApplication`.

```
public static class ExtentionForWebApplication
{
    public static void ExtendWebApplication(this IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        //Here you can use features from WebApplication
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).